# Postgres NoSQL and hibernate

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Postgres NoSQL capabilities have been for a long while.
In Java world where Hibernate/JPA is mainstream for database access,
how to use those JSON/JSOBN objects, and map them right?

For example I have several arrays of Integers (or Integer, String pairs) with size 100-200, that would fit nice to be put/saved as JSON as there is no need for identity of those elements. Or there is a Entity with `byte[]` fields.

Comment: Don't confuse `json/jsonb` columns with NoSQL.

Comment: Is anything else from Postgre NoSQL that can be used via Hibernate? I'd like to experiment, but not going to give up the ORM.

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about [OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/).

Comment: The interesting way that Postgre took, was adding NoSQL into RDMS.
If using hibernate+OGM (or other, that is not standardized contrary to JPA for SQL), than it would be the same as using 2 datasources, that would be comparable to MySQL+MongoDB.
The original idea was use newer features gradually, and stay within hibernate/JPA, that is good for classical cases.

Comment: While their marketing team seems to have embraced the term "Postgres NoSQL", Postgre**s** is still a RDBMS. ORM stands for Object **Relational** Mapper. In the linked question you can find examples on how to work with `json/jsonb` columns, but there's no built-in functionality.